# Can't get pycurl to install on cygwin: missing openssl symbols CRYPTO_num_locks etc

Tags: openssl, pycurl

I'm trying to install pycurl on Windows 7 Cygwin. I have easy_install running in that environment, but the command

`easy_install pycurl`

gives a bunch of undefined symbol errors:

```
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:688: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:688:(.text+0x70f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:689: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:689:(.text+0x716): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
build/temp.cygwin-1.7.29-x86_64-2.7/src/pycurl.o: In function `pycurl_ssl_init':
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:671: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks'
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:671:(.text+0xaf7c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `CRYPTO_num_locks'
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:679: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:679:(.text+0xafd3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:680: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/tmp/easy_install-A69Atd/pycurl-7.19.3.1/src/pycurl.c:680:(.text+0xafdf): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
```

Any ideas for a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

The `setup.py` is missing `-lcrypto` in libraries,

```
class ExtensionConfiguration(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.include_dirs = []
        self.define_macros = [("PYCURL_VERSION", '"%s"' % VERSION)]
        self.library_dirs = []
        self.libraries = []
```

changes `self.libraries` to include `crypto`:

```
self.libraries = ["crypto"]
```